# find an object from within a class

Tags: javascript

How do I find an object from within my class?

This is my stand-alone JavaScript component:

```
function User(first, last){
    if (this instanceof User){
        this.name = first + " " + last; 

        //Is there a way here to find either User objects here? (John or Jane)
        //How would I changed to the desired User object and start working with it?
    }
    else return new User(first, last);
}
```

In the client code, I have the following:

```
User("John", "Smith");
User("Jane", "Doe");
```

Comment: you have to create a class with a list of users

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What do you mean by "find either objects"? Do you want to effectively memoize the constructor so it returns an existing instance given arguments it has received before?

Comment: Is there a way to keep track of the User objects a client creates? And I see a recommendation for a User list as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would create a separate class `UserManager`. This class would be the only way to access users. Other classes would call `userManager.createUser(name)` to create a new user or `userManager.findUser(name)` to get an existing one. Ideally, the User class would be local to the manager, so no other classes can create instances directly. Whenever the UserManager creates a `new User` in the `createUser` method, it would add that user to an internal `userList` before returning it. `findUser` would then search that `userList`.

Alternatively, you could add the array of created users as a **static variable** to the `User` class. A static variable is a variable which is assigned to the class itself, not to its individual instances. Static variables are created and accessed with the syntax `Classname.variable`, so in your case `User.ALL_USERS`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! jsfiddle.net/KZm66/1 I'd like to try the static variable but I'm not sure if I'm understanding completely as far as implementing. The example I tried isn't give me an alert and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Rod You need to initialize a variable as array before you can use it as such. http://jsfiddle.net/KZm66/2/ the reason it reports 3 and not 2 is that when you create a numbered entry in an array, all below it starting from [0] are implicitly created.